# Oracle - fetch first 3 days record of the current month

Tags: sql, database, oracle, oracle11g

I need to fetch first 3 days record of the current month from Oracle database. Something like below,

```
Select * from test.purchase where create_ts=( first 3 days of the current month)
```

Comment: Welcome on SO. What have you tried?

Comment: I tried with providing those in (3 timestamp) but when month change I need to edit the query.

Answer (score 2):

```
    Select * 
from test.purchase 
where create_ts between trunc(sysdate,'mm') and trunc(sysdate,'mm') + 3
```

Comment: This will include any records at exactly midnight on the 4th too, of course, since `between` is inclusive. It's possible that isn't an issue for the OP's data; or that all values are at midnight, in which case `+ 2` would work instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the first day of the current month [with the `trunc(date)` function](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions236.htm#SQLRF06151), using the `MM` date format element.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM'), 'YYYY-MM-DD Hh24:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDA
-------------------
2017-06-01 00:00:00
```

You can then use date arithmetic to either add a number of days or an interval representing that number to get the fourth day of the month:

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') + 3, 'YYYY-MM-DD Hh24:MI:SS') from dual;

TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDA
-------------------
2017-06-04 00:00:00
```

If you want data *up to* the start of that fourth day, i.e. up to 23:59:59 on the 3rd, you can look for values *less than* midnight on the 4th:

```
select * from test.purchase
where create_ts >= trunc(sysdate, 'MM')
and create_ts < trunc(sysdate, 'MM') + 3;
```

You could potentially use `between`, but as that is inclusive you would need to specify the absolute latest time on the 3rd - checking whether the column is a date or a timestamp, which might change, and can be a little confusing. If you used `between trunc(sysdate, 'MM') and trunc(sysdate, 'MM') + 3` then you would include any records at exactly midnight on the 4th, which isn't what you want. I find using `>=` and `<` clearer and less ambiguous, even if it is a little more typing.

If the column is actually a timestamp then you can cast the calculated dates to timestamp too, and/or an use interval for the upper bound:

```
select * from test.purchase
where create_ts >= cast(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') as timestamp)
and create_ts < cast(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') + 3 as timestamp);
```

... or:

```
...
and create_ts < cast(trunc(sysdate, 'MM') as timestamp) + interval '3' day;
```